# How to handle update of a single user model data separately: user info, password, extra information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to present users with separate pages/dialogs for editing their own information. However, the information is held in a single model (called User). Now I'm trying to find the best approach for handling the update calls from partials. My code currently:

```
  def edit
    render :layout=>!request.xhr?
  end

  def edit_password
    render :layout=>!request.xhr?
  end

  def edit_extra
    unless @user.extra
      @user.build_extra
      @user.extra.value = 2047
    end

    render :layout=>!request.xhr?
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit", :layout=>!request.xhr? }
      end
    end
  end
```

The thing is, all forms in methods (edit, edit_password and edit_extra) call the update method. However, there are two problems:

1. If the data parsing isn't validated, user is presented with the "edit" form, which is incorrect.
2. I want to have a password confirmation on extra data. User shouldn't be able to edit that information unless they supply a correct password.

I would like to make more generalized solution than just duplicating the update -code. The largest problem is rendering correct layout (edit, edit_password) based on the current action.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I solved the problem by creating separate edit_section parameter that will be handled in update.

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => (t :actionsuccesful) }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        action = if params[:edit_section] then "edit_" + params[:edit_section] else "edit" end
        format.html { render :action => action, :layout=>!request.xhr? }
      end
    end
  end
```

And in forms (edit_password, etc)

```
=form_for(@user, :remote => true) do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :edit_section, "password"
```